# can't access child of OneToOneField in django?

Tags: django

I am trying to acces child of OneToOneField but I am getting the error.

```
class Products(models.Model):
    unique_id=models.CharField(max_length=13,unique=True)
    product_full_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    child_name=models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True)# name of the model connected by OneToOneField in lowercase
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_full_name)

    def selling_price(self):
        child=self.child_name
        return getattr(self,child+'_set').all().first().selling_price


class Product1(models.Model):
     product=models.OneToOneField(Products)
     selling_price=models.FloatField()
     ......

class Product2(models.Model):
     product=models.OneToOneField(Products)
     selling_price=models.FloatField()
     ......

class Product3(models.Model):
     product=models.OneToOneField(Products)
     selling_price=models.FloatField()
     ......
```

When I am trying to access get_selling_price() method I am getting error "Products object does not have any attribute product1_set" for the Products model that is connected to the Product1 model.

Comment: `getattr(a,child+'_set').all().first().selling_price` this is where the problem lies - the logic is wrong

Comment: Then, what should be the right way to do it?

Comment: To do what? I don't see any `get_selling_price` and I don't see exactly what you aim for. I commented on what I can see based on your error

Comment: But this logic is working for other models.

Comment: Can you please explain why you're fetching all elements of set , if it's a OneToOneField?

Comment: If you call the method `get_selling_price_only_for_some_models` the logic will fit perfectly

Comment: Products model is connected by only one type of product (product1,product2,product3) and as I don't know which product model is child of Products model I stored it's name and accessing it's child.

Answer (score 1):

if your children name is product1, try

```
return getattr(a,child).selling_price
```

Comment: child is not a OneToOneField

Comment: yes,i know,you should read [One-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) before code

Comment: Oh I missed that . Thanks a lot.